# How to set custom validation messages for HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, constraint-validation-api

I've got the following HTML form: http://jsfiddle.net/nfgfP/

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return(login())">
<input name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input name="pass"  type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
<br/>Remember me: <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="true" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In"/>
```

Currently when I hit enter when they're both blank, a popup box appears saying "Please fill out this field". How would I change that default message to "This field cannot be left blank"?

The type password field's error message is simply `*****`. To recreate this give the username a value and hit submit.

Comment: Why not just accept the browser default message? That's what users see for every other site they visit, you'll just confuse your users by creating a non-standard message. (Google has probably managed more UX evaluation & testing in determining that wording than you have!).

Comment: @ChrisV What about multilanguage sites?

Comment: In my case I want to check that the value is a number before posting but I can't use the type="number" attribute (for reasons.) So I set the pattern attribute to check for numbers and optional decimals which gives the message, "Please match the requested format," on error. I'd rather it said, "Ye must gift us a number bucko."

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Use [`setCustomValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API%27s_element.setCustomValidity()):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```

I [changed to vanilla JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/X8UXQ/190/) from Mootools as suggested by [@itpastorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message#comment19641023_5276722) in the comments, but you should be able to work out the Mootools equivalent if necessary.

If `setCustomValidity` is set to anything other than the empty string it will cause the field to be considered invalid; therefore you must clear it before testing validity, you can't just set it and forget.

As pointed out in @thomasvdb's comment below, you need to clear the custom validity in some event outside of `invalid` otherwise there may be an extra pass through the `oninvalid` handler to clear it.

Comment: Why when I replace elements[i] to $("#name"), it not work? And if I set 2 validation, type='number' required for example, can I set custom message different for they?

Comment: @Lai32290 because you are not accessing the actual DOM object. `$("")` returns an array of objects, even if there is only one. `$("")[i]` is most likely what you want.

Comment: I'm not saying this code is or isn't good however the point of having form validation in HTML5 is to *not* require JavaScript for form validation hence using the `oninvalid` attribute even for "purists" is utterly pointless.

Comment: This works fine for input with required attribute. However it is not applicable for input type="email". After having input the first character of your email address you fall back on standard error message "Please includ '@' to ..." I tried to trap this with else if (e.target.validity.typeMismatch) { e.target.setCustomValidity("My own message"). No success. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 495):

Here is some code to display a custom error message:

```html
<input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name"
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')"
       oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

This part is important because it hides the error message when the user inputs new data:

```
oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
```

Note: the `this` keyword is not required for inline event handlers, but you may want to use it anyway for consistency.

Comment: Note that you can even omit the `this.` in this case because inline event handlers [run with a `with(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048067/3779853) (not saying you should)

Answer (score 116):

It's very simple to control custom messages with the help of `HTML5` event `oninvalid`

Here is code:

```
<input id="UserID"  type="text" required="required"
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Witinnovation')"
       onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')">
```

This is most important:

```
onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')"
```

Comment: Also check other validations as well such as pattern, min/max values, etc... http://sanalksankar.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-validation-message.html

Comment: This causes a bug in firefox where it validates upon refresh, yet fails upon change and correction.

Comment: @RyanCharmley by using `onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"` the bug will be gone. Check my answer below.

Comment: If this does not work (it does not in Safari, for example), use `oninput` instead of `onvalid`.

Comment: @Jimothy is right about this, `oninput` is the more universal solution, `onvalid` did not work even in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 73):

**Note:** This no longer works in Chrome, not tested in other browsers.  See edits below.  This answer is being left here for historical reference.

If you feel that the validation string really should not be set by code, you can set you input element's title attribute to read "This field cannot be left blank". (Works in Chrome 10)

```
title="This field should not be left blank."
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/nfgfP/8/

And in Firefox, you can add this attribute:

```
x-moz-errormessage="This field should not be left blank."
```

#### Edit

This seems to have changed since I originally wrote this answer.  Now adding a title does not change the validity message, it just adds an addendum to the message.  The fiddle above still applies.

#### Edit 2

Chrome now does nothing with the title attribute as of Chrome 51. I am not sure in which version this changed.

Comment: I don't believe that the title attribute should be the best place for this. Perhaps the browsers should implement some other attribute and agree on it.

Comment: For declarative error messages in Firefox use the attribute: `x-moz-errormessage="This field should not be left blank."`

Comment: This adds a descriptive message under the "Please fill out this field".

Comment: @Magne This seems to have changed since I originally wrote this answer.

Comment: @kzh This *does work* in v.122 in both Chrome and MS Edge and other Chromium-based browsers, just tested. The `title` is shown to the user when the format is not met (at least with the `pattern` validation) adding a descriptive  message to the standard browser-text.

Answer (score 53):

It's very simple to control custom messages with the help of the `HTML5` `oninvalid` event

Here is the code:

```
User ID 
<input id="UserID"  type="text" required 
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('User ID is a must')">
```

Comment: it is required to set validity message to blank once control reveives input else first executed validity message will be displayed for all fields. Add oninput="setCustomValidity('')" whenever calling setCustomValidity(). +1 to Somnath's answer.

Answer (score 48):

By setting and unsetting the `setCustomValidity` in the right time, the validation message will work flawlessly.

```
<input name="Username" required 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Username cannot be empty.')" 
onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" type="text" />
```

I used `onchange` instead of `oninput` which is more general and occurs when the value is changed in any condition even through JavaScript.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked in Windows 10 1709 in the following browsers: Chrome 66.0.3359.139 64 bits, Firefox 59.0.3 (64-bit), Internet Explorer 11.431.16299.0, Edge 41.16299.402.0. Worked in macOS 10.13.2 in Safari 11.0 (13604.1.38.1.6). Worked in Android 4.4.4 in Chrome 66.0.3359.158. For those looking for the JSX way: `onInvalid={(e) => { e.target.setCustomValidity('foo') }} onChange={(e) => { e.target.setCustomValidity('') }}`.

Comment: Addendum: `e` might be null, for example when an option is removed from a React Select field. Don't forget to check for that.

Comment: Errata: to use this with React Select, you have to pass `onChange` and `onInvalid` as `inputProps={{ onInvalid: …, onChange: …, }}`

Comment: Addendum: `type='email'` is a bit more difficult to treat, since using `setCustomValidity` sets `customError: true` to `e.target.validity` even if the input is valid. I'm trying to find a way to fix it.

Comment: @GuiRitter Did you figure this out?

Comment: @EvilJordan Regarding selects, no. Regarding emails, I think I did. I'll prepare a minimum working example tomorrow and post it here.

Comment: @EvilJordan Email [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fog-whfjh?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FHello.js)

Comment: @EvilJordan Regarding selects, I remembered something: I took a very quick glance at React Forms and I think it might be able to replace native validation, but it will be a long time before I start working on this refactoring.

Comment: This comment is no longer valid. Changing setCustomValidity works in Chrome as expected.

Comment: Using `onchange` instead of `oninput` makes this work correctly with HTML5 `date` type fields.

Answer (score 43):

I have made a small library to ease changing and translating the error messages. You can even change the texts by error type which is currently not available using `title` in Chrome or `x-moz-errormessage` in Firefox. Go [check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/javanto/civem.js), and give feedback.

It's used like:

```
<input type="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please input something">
```

There's a [demo available at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnLk5ae4/).

Comment: The jsFiddle does not work. I'd love for this solution to work but it's not inspiring confidence.

Comment: @CaseyHofland you're right, I updated the jsFiddle and it's working again!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, this will surely help with localizing validation: can't believe that they didn't think about that when designing this.

Answer (score 36):

Try this one, its better and tested:

```js
    function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
        if (textbox.value === '') {
            textbox.setCustomValidity('Required email address');
        } else if (textbox.validity.typeMismatch){
            textbox.setCustomValidity('please enter a valid email address');
        } else {
           textbox.setCustomValidity('');
        }

        return true;
    }
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    <input id="email" 
           oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" 
           oninput="InvalidMsg(this);"
           name="email"  
           type="email" 
           required="required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/Sqq8e/

Comment: hey....nice solution but type=email doesnot work in safari browser . have a look http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Yes, it is not supported for safari, but I gave an answer for set custom validation message.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest and cleanest way I've found is to use a data attribute to store your custom error. Test the node for validity and handle the error by using some custom html. [image]

le javascript

```
if(node.validity.patternMismatch)
        {
            message = node.dataset.patternError;
        }
```

and some super HTML5

```
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" data-pattern-error="Please use only letters for your city." pattern="[A-z ']*" required>
```

Comment: Despite the error saying only letters, the pattern allows space and apostrophe?  Also, `A-z` allows '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', and '`'.

Answer (score 9):

The solution for preventing Google Chrome error messages on input each symbol:

```html
<p>Click the 'Submit' button with empty input field and you will see the custom error message. Then put "-" sign in the same input field.</p>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <label for="text_number_1">Here you will see browser's error validation message on input:</label><br>
  <input id="test_number_1" type="number" min="0" required="true"
         oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
         oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('This is my custom message.')"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="#">
  <p></p>
  <label for="text_number_1">Here you will see no error messages on input:</label><br>
  <input id="test_number_2" type="number" min="0" required="true"
         oninput="(function(e){e.setCustomValidity(''); return !e.validity.valid && e.setCustomValidity(' ')})(this)"
         oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('This is my custom message.')"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: On first look, I thought I knew why this works, but I can't figure it out. Could somebody explain? (how does the IIFE change this?)

Answer (score 8):

I have a simpler vanilla js only solution:

For checkboxes:

```
document.getElementById("id").oninvalid = function () {
    this.setCustomValidity(this.checked ? '' : 'My message');
};
```

For inputs:

```
document.getElementById("id").oninvalid = function () {
    this.setCustomValidity(this.value ? '' : 'My message');
};
```

Answer (score 6):

If your error message is a single one, then try below.

```html
<input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('my error message')"
       oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">  <!--  don't forget it. -->
```

To handle multiple errors, try below

```html
<input oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
<script>
inputElem.addEventListener("invalid", ()=>{
    if (inputElem.validity.patternMismatch) {
      return inputElem.setCustomValidity('my error message')
    }
    return inputElem.setCustomValidity('') // default message
})
</script>
```

### Example

You can test for input [illegal filename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) or [valueMissing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState/valueMissing).

```html
<form>
<input pattern="[^\\/:\x22*?<>|]+"
       placeholder="input file name"       
       oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
       required
>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  const form = document.querySelector("form")

  const inputElem = document.querySelector(`input`)

  inputElem.addEventListener("invalid", ()=>{   
    if (inputElem.validity.patternMismatch) {
      return inputElem.setCustomValidity('Illegal Filename Characters \\/:\x22*?<>|')
    }
    return inputElem.setCustomValidity('') // return default message according inputElem.validity.{badInput, customError, tooLong, valueMissing ...}
  })

  form.onsubmit = () => {
    return false
  }
</script>
```

- [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, oninvalid works well but it shows error even if user entered valid data. So I have used below to tackle it, hope it will work for you as well,

`oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Your custom message.')"` `onkeyup="setCustomValidity('')"`

Answer (score 2):

Adapting [Salar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322446/salar)'s answer to JSX and React, I noticed that React Select doesn't behave just like an `<input/>` field regarding validation. Apparently, several workarounds are needed to show only the custom message and to keep it from showing at inconvenient times.

I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2635), if it helps anything. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwk4yr5q2o?module=%2Fsrc%2FSelectValid.js) is a CodeSandbox with a working example, and the most important code there is reproduced here:

Hello.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SelectValid from "./SelectValid";

export default class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <SelectValid placeholder="this one is optional" />
        <SelectValid placeholder="this one is required" required />
        <input
          required
          defaultValue="foo"
          onChange={e => e.target.setCustomValidity("")}
          onInvalid={e => e.target.setCustomValidity("foo")}
        />
        <button>button</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

SelectValid.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";

export default class SelectValid extends Component {
  render() {
    this.required = !this.props.required
      ? false
      : this.state && this.state.value ? false : true;
    let inputProps = undefined;
    let onInputChange = undefined;
    if (this.props.required) {
      inputProps = {
        onInvalid: e => e.target.setCustomValidity(this.required ? "foo" : "")
      };
      onInputChange = value => {
        this.selectComponent.input.input.setCustomValidity(
          value
            ? ""
            : this.required
              ? "foo"
              : this.selectComponent.props.value ? "" : "foo"
        );
        return value;
      };
    }
    return (
      <Select
        onChange={value => {
          this.required = !this.props.required ? false : value ? false : true;
          let state = this && this.state ? this.state : { value: null };
          state.value = value;
          this.setState(state);
          if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange();
          }
        }}
        value={this && this.state ? this.state.value : null}
        options={[{ label: "yes", value: 1 }, { label: "no", value: 0 }]}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        required={this.required}
        clearable
        searchable
        inputProps={inputProps}
        ref={input => (this.selectComponent = input)}
        onInputChange={onInputChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const username= document.querySelector('#username');
const submit=document.querySelector('#submit');

submit.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(username.validity.typeMismatch){
        username.setCustomValidity('Please enter User Name');
    }else{
        username.setCustomValidity('');
    }
if(pass.validity.typeMismatch){
        pass.setCustomValidity('Please enter Password');
    }else{
        pass.setCustomValidity('');
    }

})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything new to the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

**For a totaly custom check logic:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($('#customCheck').val() != 'apple') {
      $('#customCheck')[0].setCustomValidity('Custom error here! "apple" is the magic word');
      $('#customCheck')[0].reportValidity();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $('#customCheck').on('input', function() {
    $('#customCheck')[0].setCustomValidity('');
  });


});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="dafault check with 'required' TAG" required/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="custom check for word 'apple'" id="customCheck" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla JavaScript answer. It is better to have event listeners in the scripts rather than inline HTML event listeners.

```
for(const input of document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea")){
    input.addEventListener("invalid", function(){
        input.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
    });
}
```

Answer (score -15):

Can be easily handled by just putting 'title' with the field:

```
<input type="text" id="username" required title="This field can not be empty"  />
```

Comment: This doesn't change the error message displayed. It only shows a title on the input when you hover.

Comment: This is not the correct usability of "title" to show some alert for the input field.

Comment: 'title' doesn't change the default 'required' message.

Comment: Title has a very different purpose altogether.