# How to change WebKit's error message for required HTML form fields

Tags: validation, forms, html, webkit

Gecko allows you to set the error message for [`required`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required) HTML form fields with [`x-moz-errormessage`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input#attr-x-moz-errormessage).

What's the equivalent for WebKit?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/

Answer (score 10):

While the setCustomValidity() example linked above works, it doesn't take into account the native HTML5 validation test, and instead supplies its own custom test.  If you'd instead like to use the type match / pattern match from HTML5, then use `setCustomValidity()` with an `oninvalid` event:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Custom Message')" />
```

However bear in mind that this will not be localized to the user's browser language, and will also display regardless of what is invalid (e.g. it will also display if it fails the `required` check)

Comment: Hi Jon. Can you tell me which will be the pattern for non blank field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain there isn't, and it doesn't look like it's going to happen: http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10923.

You might want to check out `setCustomValidity()`.  It seems to work fine in Chrome for me: http://olav.dk/wf2/demo/validation.asp.

**Source**: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity