# Customize form/input in validation in HTML 5

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

in HTML 5 form validation

```
<form>
<input type="txt" required id="username"/>
</form>
```

this required filed will always shows the message **"Please enter filed"**

Is there a way to customize this message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all browsers will support this attribute, Firefox does support it, IE and chrome no.
I dont know about the other browsers.

using value="Your value" mentioned above won't work. i just tried it.

i guess we have to wait till HTML5 becomes stable. to find out

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="txt" required id="username" value="Your value" />
```