# How to customize HTML5 forms required validation message?

Tags: html, validation

I have a form with an input as follows:

```
<input id="username" name="username" required>
```

Is it possible to set a custom validation message for the required field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

---

Use setCustomValidity:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```