# How to add custom HTML5 error message

Tags: html, email, input

I am using the following HTML5 code,

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
   E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

When a user submit the form with invalid email address, the user gets the error message "Please enter an email address". I need to show it in other language. Is there any wayto change the message **without using JavaScript**?

[image]

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: @eric.itzhak, But,Is posible without javascript?

Comment: @shin Not that I know of.

Comment: The whole point of native HTML5 validation is to show the messages in the user's preferred language.