# Change text of Please fill out this field tooltip in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

It is set by default that when I create input fields and set them to be required, when users don't fill in anything, they got a massage:

```
Please fill out this field
```

---

I am creating a website with Joomla, and this tooltip pops out in every browser displaying the above text. How to change the text.

I tried to look up in Joomla language ini files, but no success. Is there some easy way to change this, or some advice where it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Joomla string, it's the message displayed by the HTML5 `required` attribute. To change the message you have to check the loads of suggestions in the following questions:

- [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)
- [How to change default “please fill out this field” in two field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886428/how-to-change-default-please-fill-out-this-field-in-two-field)

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing your own component (or module/plugin), it sounds like this is the description - field in the form-xml for your component. If the form is auto-generated from a component-creator, the file should be found in 
/(administrator/)components/com_yourcomponent/models/forms

but some more info on where/what you are doing would help.

regards Jonas

Comment: I am creating a form in my articles. Simple form with required fields. So, I am using article manager. And in the article I put something like `<textarea name="blah" required></textarea>`. Therefore, on client side, when users doesn't fill in anything it gives them a notice which I want to adjust.

Comment: I didn't quite understend where should I look and change the tooltip text?