# HTML5 placeholder required - Change the default message

Tags: html, message, default, placeholder, required

I'm interested if it's possible to change the default validation message for a placeholder. 
Must be a way to made a custom message.

**My form:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML5 Placeholder</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="email" maxlength="35" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        <button type="submit">Ok</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**I've tried with JavaScript** but the message apears everytime:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('email').setCustomValidity('Please enter your e-mail!');
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="email" maxlength="35" placeholder="E-mail" required>
        <button type="submit">Ok</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e){
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid){
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e){
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```