# Can't set custom validationMessage on html5 form

Tags: html, forms, validation, translation

I have this form

```
<form id="contact-form" class="">
<input type="text" name="subject" required="required" placeholder="Subject">
<input type="text" name="phone_or_mail" required="required" placeholder="Phone number or E-mail address">
<textarea name="question" required="required" placeholder="Your Question here ..."></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="contact_form_submit"></form>
```

I try to set custom validation message, like this, but no success.

```
$('input').validationMessage = 'My error message0';
$('input[name="subject"]').validationMessage = 'My error message1 ';
$('input[name="phone_or_mail"]').validationMessage = 'My error message2';
$('textarea[name="question"]').validationMessage = 'My error message3';
```

Always shows the default message.
Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/MCD2R/

Comment: Why are you expecting any of those things to work?  Where is your documentation for `validationMessage`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood this .validationMessage thing, i have already tried the setCustomValidity(), but my form is ajax submitted and don't know where to place the code, while submit hook is not fired until all field is validated and i have to think to IE 7-9 where is no html5 validation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the work like in the mentioned  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message).

```
$('#contact-form input[name="subject"]')[0].oninvalid = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity(t('Please fill out this field!'));
    }
};
$('#contact-form input[name="subject"]')[0].oninput = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('');
};

$('#contact-form input[name="phone_or_mail"]')[0].oninvalid = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity(t('Please fill out this field!'));
    }
};
$('#contact-form input[name="phone_or_mail"]')[0].oninput = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('');
};

$('#contact-form textarea[name="question"]')[0].oninvalid = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity(t('Please fill out this field!'));
    }
};
$('#contact-form textarea[name="question"]')[0].oninput = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('');
};
```

t() is my translation function. 
The whole problem is cause of this, to get translated error messages.

IE 10- have validation fallback on submit event.

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var subject = $('input[name="subject"]');
    //if empty or value left as placeholder
    if (subject.val() == '' || subject.val() == t('Subject')) {
        subject.css('border', '2px solid red');
        return false;
    }
    var phone = $('input[name="phone_or_mail"]');
    if (phone.val() == '' || subject.val() == t('Phone number or E-mail address')) {
        phone.css('border', '2px solid red');
        return false;
    }
    var q = $('textarea[name="question"]');
    if (q.val() == '' || subject.val() == t('Your Question here ...')) {
        q.css('border', '2px solid red');
        return false;
    }
    ...
    $.ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="email" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" name="email" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);"  type="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
function InvalidMsg(textbox) {
    if (textbox.value == '') {
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Required email address');
    }
    else if (textbox.validity.typeMismatch){{
        textbox.setCustomValidity('please enter a valid email address');
    }
    else {
       textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/Sqq8e/

Answer (score 1):

**Just need to get the element and  use the method setCustomValidity.**

Example

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.setCustomValidity('custom message');
```