# data-error-message dont work in input

Tags: javascript, html

i have code that like :-

```
data-error-message="Error Enter name"
```

this attrbute not work in input type. how can i worked it.

when click submit, if any input type is empty, we must show me `data-error-message`
my code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="'.plugins_url( 'qdrah_service/js/parsley.js'  ).'"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function contact_has_done()
    {
        var ht = \'<div class="thanks" style="padding:10px; text-align:center;"><img src="'.plugins_url( 'qdrah_service/ok.png'  ).'" /><br /><br />شكرا لك , تم ارسال طلب لخدمة بنجاح سيتم الرد عليك في اقرب وقت ممكن  <br /><br /><br /><br /></div>\';
        $("#contact_area_form_").html(ht);
    }

    function error_captcha()
    {
        $("#captcha").parent(\'li\').append(\'<ul class="parsley-error-list"><li>خطأ في كود التحقق ,, حاول مجددا</li></ul>\');  
    }
    </script>

    <div id="contact_area_form_">



        <iframe name="hides" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <form data-validate="parsley" action="'.plugins_url( 'qdrah_service/ajax.php'  ).'?do=add_contact_us" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hides"> 

            <input type="hidden" name="do" value="add_contact_us" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="page_url" value="'.$pageURL.'" /> 

            <ul class="contact-us-q2-form">

                <li>
                    <label>الاسم : <span class="important">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-error-message="الرجاء كتابة الاسم كاملاً" class="medium"/>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label>البريد الإلكتروني : <span class="important">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-trigger="change" tabindex="2" data-required="true" data-type="email" data-error-message="الرجاء كتابة البريد الالكتروني بصورة صحيحة"   class="medium"/>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label>رقم الهاتف : <span class="important">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="3" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-type="alphanum" data-rangelength="[12,12]" data-error-message="يجب كتابة رقم الهاتف مكون من 12 خانة" size="12" maxlength="12" class="medium" />
                    <br><div style="float:right;text-align:right;padding-right:120px;marign-top:-20px;">مثال 9665xxxxxxx </div>

                    </li>';

                $fff = get_option('switch_on_serv_categories');

                if($fff == 2)
                {
                    $ffssf = get_option('s_s_');
                    $n=$ffssf;
                    //echo"count$ffssf"
                    if((count($n)>0))
                    {
                        if($ffssf){
                    foreach($ffssf as $k => $v)
                    {
                        $optt .= '

                        <li class="gchoice_7_1">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="' . $k . '"> 
                        <label for="choice_7_1">' . $v[name] . '</label></li>
                        ';
                    }
                    $code .= '<li>
                        <label>اختر الخدمة : <span class="important">*</span></label>
                        <ul id="input_1_7" class="tfield_checkbox">
                        ' . $optt . ' 
                        </ul>
                    </li>';
                    }}

                }


                $code .= '

                <li>
                    <label>كود التحقق<span class="important">*</span></label>
                    <img src="'.plugins_url( 'qdrah_service/captcha.php'  ).'/captcha.php" class="captcha_img" />
                    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" data-trigger="change" tabindex="6" data-required="true" data-type="alphanum" data-rangelength="[4,4]" data-error-message="يجب كتابة كود التحقق من 4 خانات" class="medium"/>

                </li>


                <li>
                    <input name="submit" class="btn_sub" type="submit" id="submit" value="إرسال  " />
                </li>


            </ul>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Where is the submit handler in your js?

Comment: i dont get any error but i need when click in `<input name="submit" class="btn_sub" type="submit" id="submit" value="إرسال  " />` and all input type empty, ineed to show error message

Comment: If you want a means to set a custom validation message for an `input`, you'll need more than just a random attribute. Start with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message), and if you can't make that work, check back here.