# HTML5 - How to set setCustomValidity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I address the input field to set the  setCustomValidity? It does not work:

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97A4G/)

```
$('#numberinput').val("").setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
```

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you could do the following:

```
$('#numberinput').get(0).setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
```

And not:

```
$('#numberinput').val("").setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
```

Comment: it does not seem to work: [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97A4G/)

Comment: It doesn't work like this, you have to call some function to validate and set your custom message. Check out the exact syntax at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441292.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is not correct. So how come this is marked as accepted answer with lots of upvotes when this is plain wrong?