# How to validate element directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to validate multi-select in angularjs. At least one item should be selected in multi-select. If not then submit button should not enable. I am using **require** to validate the form. I am able to make compulsory selection of **first name by using require**, but **how do also compulsory for multiselect**.

**Form**

```
<form ng-submit='addStudent()' name='studentForm' novalidate="">    
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="Name">First Name *</label>
        <input ng-model='student.first_name' name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required class="form-control">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="Name">Last Name </label>
        <input ng-model='student.last_name' name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
       </div>
   </div>                           
   <multi-selection selectedsubjs="student.selectedSubjects"
            allsubjects="allSubjects"
            left-title="All Subjects"
            right-title="Selected Subjects">
   </multi-selection>                              

   <input ng-disabled="sutudentForm.$invalid" type="submit">
</form>
```

**Element Directive**

```
app.directive('multiSelection', function(){
          return {
              restrict: 'E',
              scope: {
                  allsubjects: '=',
                  selectedsubjs: '=',
                  displayAttr: '@',
                  leftTitle: '@',
                  rightTitle: '@'
              },
              templateUrl: "templates/multiSelection.html",
              link: function(scope)   {
                  scope.swapsubject1 = function(item)   {
                      var index = scope.allsubjects.indexOf(item);
                      scope.allsubjects.splice(index, 1);
                      scope.selectedsubjs.push(item);
                  }

                  scope.swapsubject2 = function(item)   {
                      var index = scope.selectedsubjs.indexOf(item);
                      scope.selectedsubjs.splice(index, 1);
                      scope.allsubjects.push(item);
                  }
              }
          };
      });
```

**Multi-Select Template**

```
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="entBox">
            <switchitem ng-repeat="subj in allsubjects" value="subj.name" ng-click="swapsubject1(item)" ng-model="allSubjects"></switchitem>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="entBox">
            <switchitem ng-repeat="subj in selectedsubjs" value="subj.name" ng-click="swapsubject2(item)" ng-model="student.selectedSubjects"></switchitem>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this element is not a input type then set

```
if (!element.isInput()) {
    element[0].setCustomValidity(errorMsg);
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379999/html5-how-to-set-setcustomvalidity)