# How to set a different custom validity for different inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Can the javascript below to individually have different custom validity depending on what information is actually being entered in the field. eg. For Name: "please enter a name". For Location: "please enter a location.
The loop part in the script is confusing me a little!

**HTML**

```
<form id="sidebarform" onsubmit="return false" method="post" name="myForm" >
   <input type="text" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Name (eg. Rob James)"required><br>
   <input type="text" name="location" id="userlocation" placeholder="Location (eg. Wacol)" required><br>
   <input type="submit" id="sidebarformsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
     for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
         e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a name.");

        }
    };
    elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    };
  }
 })
 </script>
```

I was following this question for the initial custom validity.

[HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a selector other than just getting everything by tagName, and then set whatever validity you want

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#username').on({
        invalid: function (e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a name.");
             }
        },
        input: function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        }
    });

    $('#userlocation').on({
        invalid: function (e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a location.");
             }
        },
        input: function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ChB6f/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I am after.