# how to block form submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my html source to get the user to input their email in the textbox and click on the submit button to enter the site.

When a user did not put their email in the textbox, he can click on the submit button to enter to the site. I want to block it to stop them from entering the site.

Here is the code I use:

```
<div id="MainContent">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="form">
  <div id="WFItem5736404" class="wf-formTpl">
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html?u=KLlP" method="post">
            <div id="WFIcenter" class="wf-body">
                        <div class="wf-contbox">
                            <div class="wf-inputpos">
                                <input name="email" class="Email" style="position: absolute; left: 4%; bottom: 110px; width: 90%; height: 51px;" type="text" data-placeholder="yes" placeholder="Enter your Email Address...">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wf-contbox">
                            <div class="wf-inputpos">
                                <input name="submit" class="button" style="position: absolute; left: 4%; bottom: 46px; width: 92.5%; height: 56px;" type="image" src="button.png">
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="webform_id" value="5736404" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.getresponse.com/view_webform.js?wid=5736404&mg_param1=1&u=KLlP"></script>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "email");
</script>
```

I want to add the tooltip under the email textbox to force the user to input their email address before they can click on the submit to enter the site.

Can you please tell me how I can block the submit button from enter the site when the textbox is empty so I can add the tooltip under the textbox to force the user to input their email?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't validate required fields in my form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303265/cant-validate-required-fields-in-my-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `required` attribute to the `input` element like such:

```
<input required name="email" class="Email" style="position: absolute; left: 4%; bottom: 110px; width: 90%; height: 51px;" type="text" data-placeholder="yes" placeholder="Enter your Email Address...">
```

This blocks form submission until the `input` is filled-in by the user, and displays a tooltip if the user attempts to submit the form without completing the field. Here's an elucidating example of the `required` attribute from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required) and a nice explanation of the attribute from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required).

Comment: That's very interesting but w3schools claims it doesn't work in Safari, IE9 or IE8

Comment: It is supported in IE10, though.

Comment: I'm aware w3schools isn't an authority, but I imagine they're right quite often. In this case, 'required' being an HTML5 attribute, it's not surprising older versions of IE don't implement it

Comment: You're better off on SO citing the W3 specification or MDN. For instance, MDN [explains it nicely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required) and there's a browser compatibility chart included at the bottom.

Comment: Point taken, although W3Schools does provide an example in this case. I've added the MDN link to my answer.

Comment: @PaulD thank you very much for your help. I can see the tooltip go under the textbox with a text "please fill out this field". Is it possible to change it?

Comment: You are very welcome. Yes, it is possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the `submit` event and prevent its default (submit) behavior with [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/1auajg2k/)

### Javascript (pure)

```
var form = document.getElementById('yourFormId');
form.onsubmit = function (ev) {
   if (!inputDataIsValid()) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      alert('invalid input data');
   }
};
```

Note: If you use jQuery you can do the same by:

```
$('.form-selector').on('submit', function (ev) {
   if (!inputDataIsValid()) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      alert('invalid input data');
   }
});
```

Comment: If IE8 or below support is not needed, [`form.addEventListener()`](http://jsfiddle.net/1auajg2k/2/) is a better option.

Comment: @Matyas thank you very much for this, but i have a problem. how i can use the javascript to work with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `required pattern="[^ @]+@[^ @]+.[a-z]+"` at the end of your input[name=email] tag, like so:

```
<input name="email" class="Email" style="position: absolute; left: 4%; bottom: 110px; width: 90%; height: 51px;" type="text" data-placeholder="yes" placeholder="Enter your Email Address..." required pattern="[^ @]+@[^ @]+.[a-z]+" />
```

This goes beyond simply check for something is entered.
This would also check for email syntax validity.