# Change error message "invalid date" in input type="date"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to change the default message "Invalid date" by the french equivalent "Date invalide" for an input type="date" in HTML or JS/JQuery.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you tried creating custom validation message using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message/5276722#5276722 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
<input type="date" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Date invalide')" />
```

It's pretty well supported

Answer (score 0):

to change the default validation message refer this code
   `<input type="date" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Date Invalid ')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" />`

hope this is what you are asking for
there is a bug with george's ans which is seen when you give wroung input once and re edit to enter the correct one and submit the form

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this civem.js script [Custom Input Validation Error Messages script](https://github.com/javanto/civem.js)