# How to change built-in default date_select notice message for invalid date in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the `date_select` method for my form in Rails.

Whenever I choose an invalid date such as February 30th or April 31st, I get a default notice message stating, "invalid date" which I believe is built-in.

How would I change this to something custom like "The date you have entered is invalid." ?

I'd like for this message to be consistent with the capitalization and punctuation in the rest of my app.

Comment: Get the message from where? Is this a model-level validation? We need code for context.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where this message is coming from. I'd presume it's built-in within `date_select` for invalid date combinations as I haven't written this code. 
 
If I were to guess, it must be a model-level validation and the flash notice message appears on my view once I try to submit my form with an invalid date.

Comment: Provide your form code and model

Comment: Not sure how it's relevant but added

Comment: Where and how is the error message showing up? Do it look like a default Rails error message or as a message from the browser? Do you use a frontend library (javascript) that might create that message?

Comment: Looks like one of the default green Rails flash messages that prevents me from submitting the form.

Not using any JS or front-end library.

Might be relevant to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508093/change-error-message-invalid-date-in-input-type-date but I don't have any JS

Comment: What does your HTML look like ? An `<input type="date">` has built-in browser validation, I'm not sure that Rails has anything to do with that.

Comment: I see `<div id="notice">invalid date</div>` when I Inspect Element my webpage but the div tag is not anywhere in the code that I've written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails raise an ArgumentError with hard core message 'invalid date' whenever convert time failed (extension Time-Zone and Time-Calculations)

But in your case, we don't need to intercept or override any code in models/controllers, just use a helper method to convert 'invalid date' message (or whatever messages you want) before they're rendered, right ?

```
# helper
def format_error(error)
 return ArgumentError.new(I18n.t 'date.invalid') if error.class == ArgumentError && error.message == 'invalid date'

 error
end

# view
<% interval.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
   <li><%= format_error(message) %></li>
<% end %>
```

By the way, what version of Rails are you using ? I use Rails 6 and whenever i pick wrong day it will be automatically converted to next valid day, for example: i pick 31/4 -> then it'll be saved as 1/5.

Comment: Really thought this would work but unfortunately I'm still getting the original "invalid date" message. I'm using Rails 6.0.3.6.

Comment: In that case, I thought that in your code (maybe you override ActiveRecord save/update, are you ?) some where throw directly the ArgumentError, 'invalid date'  without add to `ActiveModel.errors`. (for example: you can test by add one line code `"31/04/2021".to_date`). In that case, you need to wrap your code in begin .. rescue => error, then format that error then add to your `ActiveModel.errors`.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I ended up doing actually! Your comment definitely put me on the right path