# How to change jquery required message without using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, required

I am so confused right now. I'm trying to change all required messages in my website but all I see everywhere is that you can do it via jquery validator plugin. But I ain't using this, I am only using twitter bootstrap css and jss, plus jquery 1.11.1

This is how I link a required message for an input :

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

How can I change required message without using jquery validator?

Thx

Comment: There's already an answer for this... Check the following out.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5276722/1293740

You're using just HTML `required` attribute, so you will be able to set different message like this with JS.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery.  The validation messages are via your browser and HTML5.