# How can i style form validation messages?

Tags: html, validation

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " name="username"  placeholder="Enter ID " required >
```

I have to change the position of validation which tells please fill out details to rightside of textbox.I have to change validation message to "Enter Username".How to implement those?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Comment: Are you using some third party validation script?

Comment: I got it ..This code works for custom validation messages                        <input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name"
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  />

Comment: @Ramaya,Great, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For custom validation messages i got an answer

```
<input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
```