# how to validate data from form using javascript, then call php page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with an action attribute that calls another php page, however I'd like to validate first that one text field is not empty using javascript, how can I do this from the `<input type"submit">` tag?

Comment: Do you think add your codes to your question ?

Comment: I'm not submitting this as an answer since I'm recommending a plugin, but this is a great validation tool:

[jquery.validate()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: That level of input validation can be done without javascript (html5), no need for javascript, and certainly not a huge library like jquery.

Answer (score 1):

In html5: 
`<input type="text" [...] required="required" />`
will allow supporting browsers to force the user to enter something before allowing the form to be submitted.

Regardless of solution: do not trust in your php code that it was validated on the client nor that it was your form to start with that sent the input to your script. So redo all validation on the server in the php code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, is there a way to edit what the message says when it prompts that the field is required?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message