# Required field custom validation message in Google Chrome in input tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, required, requiredfieldvalidator

```
<form>
    <input type="text" required     x-moz-errormessage="Fill this out." />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

this will display "Fill this out." in Firefox when text input box is not filled.
But in Google Chrome it shows "Please fill out this field", which is the default error message for required field.
What is the alternate syntax for
`x-moz-errormessage`  in Chrome

By the way I want to do it without JavaScript, it should defined in the input tag only as an attribute.

Comment: You might find this article informative: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Comment: But what is the alternate syntax for
x-moz-errormessage in Chrome so that I can display the custom error message.

Comment: There isn't one. You have to use javascript and call setCustomValidity. Read the linked article, it has good examples.

Comment: You can find the working solution here.
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22394824/9762498)