# Where to define the field required error message

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I've got a simple sign up form including this line

```
    <%= f.label :password, 'Password:' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, required: true %>
```

now if someone tries to sign up and leaves the password blank, there's an error flashed in the form. Where can I define what this error actually says?

Comment: Take a look at https://jqueryvalidation.org/ I just started using this for client-side validation, really happy with the results.

Comment: @KevinEtore thank you for reposting this comment :)

Comment: @krawallla np, hopefully this is something you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set custom message for required attribute using [setCustomValidity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)
But to do that you need to do some js coding.
So, I think you can have a workaround by doing this in rails

```
<%= f.password_field :password, onchange: "if ($('#password').val().length == 0) { alert('Password field is blank(custom text)!'); }" %>
```

I have not tested this but I think this will work