# Form visually hidden field and required validation use

Tags: html, jquery, forms, validation

I have an HTML5/Bootstrap form with hidden fields:
`style="display: none"`

which i show/hide via jQuery:

```
show() | hide()
```

For field validation i use the attribute **required**.

I want to have all my hidden fields as required but when some of them don't appear then the form can't proceed to submission.

Any thoughts about how can i have validation enabled only to fields displayed by user selections?

Comment: When you show/hide the fields, why not also change the required attribute?

Comment: Thank you could you give me an example? There are a lot show/hide

Comment: To remove: `$('#your-element-id').removeAttr('required');​​​` To add
`$("#your-element-id").attr("required", true);`​​

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that my show/hide jQuery is a bit big. There are 4 dependent dropdown fields. Is there any other mass option or do i have to check them one by one and add the new rule?

Comment: Please provide code so we can understand better your problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this trick:

inside HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required="required" class="input-hidden">
```

CSS class:

```
.input-hidden{
        height:0;
        width:0;
        visibility: hidden;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        float:right;
}
```

Comment: Super. This worked for me. But is there any way to show a message that this value is missing? By default submit?

Comment: @Augus maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20189012/1322034

Answer (score 3):

You can add a class name for all the required attributes in the html:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" class="card-payment-info" required>
<input type="text" name="last_name" class="card-payment-info" required>
```

and, from js event like a click, you can enable or disable the required attributes:

```
// disable require:
$(".card-payment-info").attr('required', false);
// enable require
$(".card-payment-info").attr('required', true);
```

Comment: It's `.prop()`, not `.attr()` for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class `.hideable` to your **hideable required** inputs.
Then use these functions instead of your show() and hide():

```
function show1() {
//Your show() code here
$('.hideable').attr('required', 'required');
}
function hide1() {
//Your hide() code here
$('.hideable').removeAttr('required');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Change the form to "novalidate"

2 - Catch the submit event

3 - Force the browser to check individually each visible input with input.reportValidity()

```
$('form')
  .attr('novalidate', true)
  .on('submit', function(){
    var isValid = true;
    $('input:visible,select:visible,textarea:visible', this).each(function() {
      // report validity returns validity of input and display error tooltip if needed
      isValid = isValid && this.reportValidity();
      // break each loop if not valid
      return isValid;
    });
    // do not submit if not valid
    return isValid;
  })
```

I've made a JQuery tool for this that also uses a mutation observer to automatically apply on dynamically created forms.

https://github.com/severinmoussel/VisibilityFormValidator/blob/master/VisibilityFormValidator.js

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a drop-in replacement for the built-in `show()` and `hide()` that removes `required` on `hide` and restores them back on `show` (for all child elements).

```js
(function ($) {
    var oldShow = $.fn.show;
    $.fn.show = function () {
        oldShow.apply(this, arguments); //run the original "show" method
        this.find("[notrequired]").prop("required", true).removeAttr("notrequired");
        return this;
    };
    var oldHide = $.fn.hide;
    $.fn.hide = function () {
        oldHide.apply(this, arguments); //run the original "hide" method
        this.find("[required]").prop("required", false).attr("notrequired", "1");
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

UPD: published as a gist here in case anyone wants to add anything https://github.com/alex-jitbit/jquery-required-visibility/blob/main/showhide.js

Answer (score 0):

You can add `pointer-events: none;`, so the user can't click on the hidden element and also the cursor doesn't change when you hover it. As [@DeadApe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14546398/deadape) answered in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65356856/6938902

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to write your own validation-function:

This function checks all textareas and inputs in the default way, but first check if the input is displayed.

```js
function validateFormOnlyVisableInputs(elForm) {
    var inputs = elForm.querySelectorAll("input, textarea");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        // display:none inputs ignorieren
        if (inputs[i].offsetParent === null) continue;
        if (!inputs[i].checkValidity()){
            inputs[i].reportValidity();
            return false;
        } 
            
    }
    return true;
}
```

You have to add an eventlistener to the submit-button and call the valdation function:

```js
 
 // this is out of a class, so you have to remove this...
 // if you have problems you can write me ;)
 this.elSendButton = this.elForm.querySelector("Button");

 this.elSendButton.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (validateFormOnlyVisableInputs(this.elForm)) {
        this.elForm.submit();
        ...
```