# Make a visually hidden field required

Tags: html

This is my code:

```html
 <label for="uploadFile" class="custom-uploadFile">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> UPLOAD ID
  </label>
  <input class="form-control input-lg"  name="picture" id="uploadFile" type="file" style="display:none;" required>
```

I *want* to let this upload field be required, but the input is hidden.

I must use some JavaScript. Or what can I use to solve this problem? I watched a lot of tutorials, but they did not work!

Comment: @Turing85 my question is how to let this field required

Comment: input is hidden because of the property `display: none`. Moreover, do not use inline css.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to see the form validation message you can hide the input using opacity.

```css
#uploadFile {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  float: left; /* Reposition so the validation message shows over the label */
}

div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input name="picture" id="uploadFile" type="file" required>

<label for="uploadFile">Upload label</label>
    
<div><input  name="submit" type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: the form element now no longer HIDDEN, it just INVISIBLE. 

"hidden" input take no space on the form, 
while the "invisible" input still took space (width/height) in the form

Comment: You can't just make the input hidden since that's gonna also hide the validation message, but there is a few hacks you can probably use to better mimic a hidden input with pros/cons.

Comment: I added width: 0; so the input doesn't take width space. Thanks for you input.

Comment: .input-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
} // setting padding: 0; won't show required validation error. so don't set padding to 0;

Comment: Is this the right solution though? Is there any accessiblity reasons to not do this?

Comment: It's a bit better that other hacks to hide the upload input since you can still select the input with tab. But nothing will be highlighted to let you know it's selected.

Answer (score 3):

But I think it's a nice approach and I also added

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to the input. So the user can't click on it and also the cursor doesn't change on hover.

Answer (score 0):

This what have worked for me, you can't set the height to 0:

```
   input {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 1px;
        display: block
   }
```