# How to customize HTML5 forms patterns validation message without changing required validation message?

Tags: html5-canvas

I want change only patterns validation message but without changing required validation message.In addition, I want change full patterns validation message

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```js
 $("#submit").click(function(){
   $("#email")[0].oninvalid =function(e) {
     if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter the email address");
     }
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
     <input class="form-control" id ="email"  type="text"
        placeholder="Email address" required/>
   
    <button type= "submit" id = "submit">Submit</button
</form>
```

Comment: This one show only this error message but I want show with required error message