# Custom validation for HTML5 Input type time but not required?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am trying to put custom validation on `HTML5` input control `time`. I am able to successfully put the custom validation but it's also making it required even tough required is false for the control.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="time" value="8:00"
  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter Valid Time')"
  oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

I also tried `title` attribute but didn't work. Input could be not required.

**Update:**
Following code is working now:

```
<input type="time" value="8:00"
  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter Valid Time')"
  oninput="this.setCustomValidity(''); return false;"/>
```

It shows me perfect validation if I put invalid value and click on Submit,but when I clear it and click on submit it is forcing me to have value in the `textbox` even tough it is not required.

Comment: Did you try having return false; at the end of your functions? Also why does one function call start with "this." and the other doesn't?

Comment: Return false; on invalid? I copied the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I tried `return false;` at the end of `oninput` function and it worked. Now, if I click on "x" button on `input` to clear the time then it works fine but if I go to time and remove time with backspace it still gives the validation.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I updated my question please check.

Comment: It looks like having an empty value may constitute being invalid.  From the accepted answer of the stackoverflow link you attached, this code:                   if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }        you may want to investigate this condition for empty strings