# Change required input message in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to change the alert (Please fill out this field) in React.

Example:

A Form component and an Input component.

PD: I am able to do it in a simple HTML with JS, but I just can't get it working with React

PD2: I know I can use the stated to validate and throw custom error messages, but I just have to do it using the required alert promp

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: Can you please share your attempts with JS and HTML? Also, have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply this piece of code inside the component of the input that you want to change the alert:

```
htmlInput.oninvalid = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("Here is your text!");
};
```

Also here is an example of use in a component:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var htmlInput = document.getElementById("id");
    htmlInput.oninvalid = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("This can't be left blank!");
    };
}
```

Comment: If the inputs are empty, you get stuck in validation. It is necessary to clean them after the `oninvalid`:     `htmlInput.oninput = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity(' ');
    };`

Answer (score 4):

###### i managed to solve this like this

```
onInvalid={F => F.target.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')} 
onInput={F => F.target.setCustomValidity('')}
```

Comment: Please add external resources (e.g. official docs) to prove the validity of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answeres helped me, this is easiest way
Just add this in your props ex:

```
  onInvalid={e => e.target.setCustomValidity("Code is required")}
```

Comment: this line as well

onInput={e => e.target.setCustomValidity("")}

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.

Comment: Hello! just add that line in your input element for example to have the custom message

Comment: No, I mean edit it with an explanation.