# How can I change the default text for html validation to a custom error message

Tags: html, validation

I need to know, How can I change the default text for each html validation to a custom error message.

I read this article:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

And this is my html code:

```
<form>
  <input id="choose" name="i_like" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the message is :

> Please fill out this field.

The question is , I want to change this default error message.

EDITED:

And also I want to define a fixed message and change a part of this message as custom error message for validation, at this time this is my second problem.

e.g:

**"Please enter [----] before send"**

Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setCustomValidity` method to define your own custom error message.
And about your second issue, you should define a function, and set name attribute for passing keyword to your fixed message.

Declare a Javascript function:

```
<script>

    function applyValidation(x){

        var msg = "Please enter"+ x.name +" before send"
        x.setCustomValidity(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Then Use it in your html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="choose" name="input-name1" 
    required oninvalid="applyValidation(this)"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  />

    <input type="text" id="choose" name="input-name2" 
    required oninvalid="applyValidation(this)"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  />

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: this is correct and worked. but what about my second problem?