# how to set Annotation (notes) on a form as required

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I have a customized form of a customized entity, on my form I have crm annotation (notes), I need to set the notes part as required (according to a rule) how do I do that? when I clicked on the notes field I couldn't see the field name, Is it possible ?
The question reffers to dynamics crm annotation mechanism

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message)

Comment: @Tygo nope, I 'm talking about dynamics-crm

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot achieve this straight forward, as we know Notes (annotation) is a separate entity which may have many records for a parent entity record. This is not a simple field in form, cannot be accessed in business rule. Instead of showing in subgrid, Platform giving different UI/UX for notes only like Timeline etc.

You can write script to validate/prompt user to create a child note on need basis. But not before creating a parent record itself.

This was already [discussed in community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/268488), maybe you can have a custom mandatory multiline field to capture notes & rollup to annotation, can handle different scenarios/validations in code.