# How to change default red color when using required and the input is invalid in html

Tags: html, css

I have some code like this. When I did not put any input in last name or first name and click submit button, it shows me the red color in border. I know that's because I use required in both of them. But I am wondering is there a way to change that red color to other colors (like green for example)?

```
<body>
<form id="form">
<input id="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
<input id="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="first Name" required/>
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="save">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look at this post which change a custom validation message  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: In your case you get red color in the border so it may help

Comment: I was trying to answer then your question got closed lmao. Just use input:invalid{ //customize it here } in your css or style tag and you're done. :)