# Javascript form validation not working in the browser properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a application using pure javascript approach that validates a registration form. The form has five controls: username, password and retype password fields, a checkbox that allows the user to toggle the password visibility and submit button.

I am having some issues trying to understand why my code is not working properly on the browse.

1. The error messages are not showing.
2. The button submit is not sending to the confirmation page " I've
   tried constantly to solve it but no result".
3. The check password match is not working.

I hope I explained well.

Many thanks.

> Here is the second HTML page for the form submission.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <p>Form Successfully Submitted</p>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

> Here is my javascript code CSS AND HTML.

```js
function handleInvalidities(input) { // Takes input field as parameter
    let errMsg = "";
    if (!input.validity.paternMismatch) { // Check for wrong format
        errMsg = "Invalid entry. Enter your details in the format shown.";
    }
    if (input.validity.valueMissing) {
        errMsg = "Invalid entry. This field can not be blank. Please enter a value."; // Check for missing fields
    }
    return errMsg;
}

function displayInvalidities(errMsg, elem) {
    let elemPos = document.getElementById(elem);
    let errElem = document.createElement("span");
    errElem.setAttribute("class", "error");
    let errText = document.createTextNode(errMsg);
    errElem.appendChild(errText);
    elemPos.parentNode.insertBefore(errElem, elemPos.nextSibling);
}

function cleanUpErrors() {
    let errors = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
    for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        errors[i].style.display = "none"; // Clear up existing error messages
    }
}

function Toggle() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("password");
    if (temp.type === "password") {
        temp.type = "text";
    } else {
        temp.type = "password";
    }
}

function checkPasswordMatch (registerForm) { 
 let originalPassword = registerForm.password.value;
 let retypedPassword = registerForm.retypedpassword.value; 
 if (originalPassword === retypedPassword) { 
  return true; 
 } else {
  let passwordMatchError = document.getElementById("passwordmatcherror"); 
  passwordMatchError.setAttribute("class", "error");
  passwordMatchError.innerHTML = ("Passwords do not match. Please retype");
  return false;
 }
}

window.onload = () => {
    let registerForm = document.getElementById("regsiterdetails"); // Get the form and add event listener to it
    registerForm.addEventListener("submit",
        (event) => {
            if (!checkPasswordMatch(registerForm)) {
                event.preventDefault(); // If no match stop form submitting 
            }
        }, false);
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 0.75rem;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 1rem;
}

label {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0.25rem 0 0.25rem 0;
}

#showpasswordslabel {
 display:inline;
}

#showpasswords {
 width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

.error {
 width:15%;
 min-width: 240px;
 display: block;
 padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
 color: white;
 background-color: #900;
 margin: 0.5rem;
 border: 2px solid transparent;

}

input:not(#showpasswords) {
 width:15%;
 min-width: 240px;
 height: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #B2B2B2, -1px -1px 1px #292929;
    position: relative;

}

button {
 margin-top: 1rem;
 border: none;
 background: #3498db;
 width: 80px;
 height: 35px;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #292929, -1px -1px 1px #B2B2B2;
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: all .3s;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

button:hover {
 background: #2980b9;
}

button:focus {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #B2B2B2, -1px -1px 1px #292929;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JavaScript</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
 <section>
  <h1>Form: validated using Javascript</h1>
  <p>Try entering the following:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Password longer or shorter than 8 characters and/or without an uppercase, lowercase or a numeric.</li>
   <li>Passwords that do not match</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Register</h2>

  <p>* = Required Field</p>
  <div id="formcontainer">
   <form id="regsiterdetails" action="fma_t3confirm.html" onsubmit="validateForm(event)"></form>
   <div>
    <label for="username">* Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" required>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="password">* Password (Must be 8 characters and include one uppercase, one lowercase and one
     numeric):</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,8}$" required>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showpasswords" onclick="Toggle()">
    <label id="showpasswordslabel" for="showpasswords">Show passwords</label>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="retypedpassword">* Retype your password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="retypedpassword">
    <span id="passwordmatcherror"></span>
   </div>
   <div>
    <button type="submit" id="registerButton">Register</button>
   </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
<script src="scripts/fma_t3.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `validateForm` is not defined. You're setting `onsubmit` twice (once in HTML, and again in your `window.onload` handler). Use `addEventListener` instead of `onload`. I recommend transferring your JavaScript to TypeScript to catch typing errors.

Comment: Why not just use native validation error messaging? You can set custom validation messages: [HTML5 form required attribute. Set custom validation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272433/215552)

Comment: thx guys. the problem was fixed.