# Custom validity input box html

Tags: html, validation, input, required, requiredfieldvalidator

I am trying to create a form with the input type text box with two conditions.
**1**) validate empty field.
**2**) white space not allowed.
I have added pattern, everything is working fine when empty box, it says *Please fill the empty field*, and when user puts space in the username it says *Please match the format requested*, but the problem is that I am trying to replace default *Please match the format requested* with *White space not allowed*. But I am unable to find any solution anywhere.

My code is listed below:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="\S+" required >
</form>
```

Comment: I believe this has been answered here. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: I have tried this already but it will replace blank field validator and  show only custom message even if box is empty or with white space.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add client side code to support what you're wanting to do with setCustomValidity with a check against the value it found. Like so:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {

        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                if ( e.target.value.match(/[\s\t]+/i) ) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("White space not allowed");
            } else {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }

        }
    };
    elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    };
}
```