# How to preventDefault in forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I  have a form with some inputs, and I want to make an js validation for that form. But, `preventDefault` is not working for me.

HTML Code

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <h2>Send us a message</h2>
    <div class="input-box" id="nameInputBox">
        <small class="errorMsg-hidden">error msg</small>
        <input type="text" name="" required id="name">
        <span>Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
         <input type="submit" name="" value="Nosūtīt" id="submit">
     </div>
</form>
```

JS Code

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const name = document.getElementById('name');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In this case, it is important to keep the required attribute in html, because some of styling depends of `:valid` pseudo class.

Is there any solution here?

Comment: "it is important to keep the required attribute in html"? You haven't changed an attribute. You don't even have an input type submit or button.

Comment: Not seeing a field in your form that submits?

Comment: oh, sorry, i forgot to add submit button code to form code I added here. Edits made.  @StackSlave

Comment: When you `eventObject.preventDefault()` on submit of a `<form>` it stops submission. You are supposed to use `FormData` with the `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Given your comment on Tiffany's answer, your question is really about custom error messages; `.preventDefault()` isn't the real issue.

Comment: Have you read the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message? Given your apparent focus on custom error messages, this would seem to address your problems?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `e.stopPropagation();`

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const name = document.getElementById('name');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
<h2>Send us a message</h2>
<div class="input-box" id="nameInputBox">
    <small class="errorMsg-hidden">error msg</small>
    <input type="text" name="" required id="name">
    <span>Name</span>
</div>
</form>
```

Question was little bit confusing.
May be this will work... "user" is valid username (Just for test)

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');

var subMit = function(event) {
    let name = document.getElementById('name');
    if(name.value === "user"){
        document.getElementById('ChangeName').textContent = name.value;
      document.getElementById('errorMsg-hidden').textContent = "Looks Good";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('errorMsg-hidden').textContent = "Validation Error";
    }
    event.preventDefault();
};

form.addEventListener("submit", subMit, true);
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
<h2>Send us a message</h2>
<div class="input-box" id="nameInputBox">
    <small id="errorMsg-hidden">error msg</small><br>
    <input type="text" name="" required id="name"><br>
    <span id="ChangeName">Name</span>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but this did not help me this time

Comment: And in what way did it "not help"? What do you require that this answer didn't resolve? How is Tiffany meant to improve her answer if you don't explain where her attempt failed, and what's necessary?

Comment: When I press the Submit button of my form, I want to add custom error messages, if the values of inputs do not validate. 
With code provided by Tiffany, form is still showing default error messages, if the values of inputs do not validate. Actutally, they even do not validate at all, if I have one of the fields empty. It just keeps showing the default error message, that the certain field cannot be empty. @DavidsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: You shouldn't (don't) need `.stopPropagation()` to prevent the form submission — the `.preventDefault()` should do it. In fact, I can not reproduce the OP's issue; if I put that exact HTML and code on my local webserver it _does_ prevent the form submission.

Comment: @predefined: "*with code provided by Tiffany, form is still showing default error messages*" - because that wasn't mentioned in your question, and is therefore not addressed in Tiffany's answer. Can you please edit your question to explain in detail what you want to achieve? And how/where your current code fails, that way people can try to help.

Comment: It's `window.onsubmit = function(event) {event.preventDefault();}` though close enough. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some css when your input is valid or not, just bind each input to a `onChange()`. Check validity through these functions and when one input is valid or not juste add to it a specific css class. You don't need `:valid` anymore.

Comment: Your statement seems odd to me, because built-in form validation and `:valid` pseudo-attribute exist so don't have to add onChange handlers to everything, not the other way around. Listening for every _change_ event is the _bad old way_ of doing form validation.