# How to overwrite default error message in primeng dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, primeng

can anyone help me to customize the default error message in p-dropdown

Here is the code:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="vehicleList" [(ngModel)]="selectedVehicle" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Select" optionLabel="label" [showClear]="false" dropdownIcon="pi pi-caret-down" required requiredMessage="Please select the vehicle">
```

[Please find the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQHTF.png)

need to change the "Please select item in list" error message to "Select a vehicle".

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message). It might help you to achieve what you want.